# Replacing all spaces with underscores in a text file with unix

Tags: bash, unix, txt

Sorry if this is a repeat question; I am very green with unix.

I have several (n = 12) text files that contain spaces in the first column that should all be changed to underscores. The files are of phylogeny ID and counts in different samples, see example below.

```
phylodist   all_Tg_3300056613   all_Tg_3300056890   all_Tg_3300057214   all_Tg_3300057270   all_Tg_3300057271
Archaea;Candidatus Diapherotrites;unclassified Candidatus Diapherotrites;unclassified Candidatus Diapherotrites;unclassified Candidatus Diapherotrites;Candidatus Iainarchaeum;Candidatus Iainarchaeum andersonii;Candidatus Iainarchaeum andersonii SCGC AAA011-E11 (contamination screened)   5.91123918323401        12.3266217289478        2.01841255189448        0   0
Archaea;Candidatus Korarchaeota;unclassified Candidatus Korarchaeota;unclassified Candidatus Korarchaeota;unclassified Candidatus Korarchaeota;Candidatus Korarchaeum;Candidatus Korarchaeum cryptofilum;Candidatus Korarchaeum cryptofilum OPF8        419.386679750923        502.442103336035        446.524450581103    0   0
Archaea;Candidatus Micrarchaeota;unclassified Candidatus Micrarchaeota;unclassified Candidatus Micrarchaeota;unclassified Candidatus Micrarchaeota;Candidatus Mancarchaeum;Candidatus Mancarchaeum acidiphilum;Candidatus Mancarchaeum acidiphilum Mia14        7.5272438877384 4.95622132293645        0   0   0
Archaea;Candidatus Thermoplasmatota;Candidatus Poseidoniia;Candidatus Poseidoniales;unclassified Candidatus Poseidoniales;unclassified Candidatus Poseidoniales;uncultured Candidatus Poseidoniales archaeon;Candidatus Poseidoniales archaeon AHCG     5.15021284928401        6.49674226828345        0   0   0
```

My goal is to upload the files to R as a DESeq2 object, separated by ";". What is a simple way to process all my files?

Comment: Please post the sample data in a way that preserves the lines. Put it in a code block instead of quotation.

Comment: Your title says you want to replace all spaces, but the question text says only the first space. Which is it?

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `sed` command:

```
sed -i 's/ /_/' *.txt
```

Since there's no `g` modifier in the substitute command, this will replace just the first space in each line with an underscore.